# IE not displaying images as per css file

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am developing a web application. I am having a css file

```css
body.login {
    background: url('abc.jpg')
}
body.loginSuccess {
    background: url('xyz.jpg')
}
```

In Chrome it is working fine(that is in the login page, the image abc is displayed and in the loginSuccess page, the image xyz is displayed)

But in IE, the same image abc is displayed in both the pages.
Why?

Comment: what is the output html like? does it get the .loginSuccess class in ie?

Comment: are you using javascript to add the .loginSuccess class name to body tag ? if so check if that is getting appended properly in IE..

Answer (score 0):

Do one of the following:

- Press `Contrl+F5` to reload all resources with no cache
- Clear the cookies and cached files (Tools > Internet Options)
- Try suffixng path eg `url(abc.jpg?v=123)`